# Android 10 WiFi API scanning for available networks

Tags: android, mobile-application, android-10.0, wifimanager

How to develop a WiFi scanning feature in Android 10 SDK? As I understand that WifiManager APIs have been deprecated. Is there any other solution to developing the exact feature using a diferent API approach?

Feature to scan available WiFi networks and display in Activity in Android 10 and higher